# PhpStorm 8 Interpreter reads wrong php.ini when looking for xDebug on a Vagrant machine

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I've been trying to set up xDebug with Vagrant and PhpStorm 8. It is supposed to simplify the process a lot, but for me it was exactly the opposite. In PhpStorm 8 we can set up Interpreters on a Vagrant maching. This is my setup.

[image]

The connection is set up - no problem here, the PHP binary is also found and responding. However, you can see the message `Debugger: Not installed`.

PhpStorm does not detect xDebug because it is looking at the CLI config file (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`) instead of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, where debugger is installed.

I find it rather strange that it would look for the Cli config while it is usually a different config file for web servers.

How can I make PhpStorm detect the debugger? Should I copy all configuration from `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` to `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (these are substantially different in my remote environment and I want to keep them different). Has anyone encountered the same prblem?

Comment: Everything is correct here. Don't worry about that message.

Comment: Remote PHP Interpreter is to be used by PhpStorm over SSH in a CLI mode .. (e.g. executing PHPUnit tests/normal scripts). PhpStorm does not specify (and cannot influence in any way) what PHP interpreter/config will be used when you execute your scripts via browser (on remote server).

Comment: Simply speaking: when IDE detects your debugger engine .. it executes something like `php -i` (or possibly some simple script with `<?php phpinfo();` kind of string) -- it just parses it's output. Since it's executed over SSH (which is a CLI mode), the PHP itself chooses to use `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` config file.

Comment: If you plan to execute/debug your scripts over SSH in CLI mode.. then you have to make appropriate changes in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file, otherwise it will not affect your Apache.

Comment: If you actually need such info -- then you can verify it at the same place where you configure path mappings for remote debugging: `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers` -- use `Validate remote environment` button for that (NOTE: you have to setup Deployment entry (SFTP is the most obvious) to have it working).

Comment: @LazyOne indeed, the status of debugger in the interpreters dialogue does not affect xDebug connection with IDE. It's all good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, PS is supposed to look at the Cli config, because it executes the PHP binary other SSH. I have a separate ini file for each PHP Module and I use the same in Web Server and Cli configuration.
In my `php5/cli/conf.d` folder I have symlinks pointing to the modules in my `mods-available` folder.

```
|-- cli
|   |-- conf.d
|   |   |-- 05-opcache.ini -> ../../mods-available/opcache.ini
|   |   |-- 10-mysqlnd.ini -> ../../mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
|   |   |-- 10-pdo.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo.ini

|   -- php.ini
|-- mods-available
    |-- curl.ini
    |-- gearman.ini
    |-- imagick.ini
    |-- intl.ini
    |-- mcrypt.ini
    |-- mongo.ini
    |-- mysqli.ini
    |-- mysql.ini
    |-- mysqlnd.ini
    |-- opcache.ini
    |-- pdo.ini
    |-- pdo_mysql.ini
    |-- readline.ini
```

Comment: This is neat. I like the idea of shared modules.